# Configurar API para banco de dados SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sequelize-js

Tenho uma API que eu utilizava com MySQL, mas tive que mudar pra SQL Server. Infelizmente nunca usei SQL Server, não sei se precisa baixar algo pra conseguir. A API foi feita em JS. A configuração do sequelize da minha API com MYSQL era assim:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');    

const config = {
    user: "root",
    database: "api",
    password: "",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    max: 10000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3000
};

const seq = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    {
        host:config.host,
        dialect:config.dialect,
        port:config.port,
        logging: false,
        pool: {
            max: config.max,
            min: 0,
            idle: config.idleTimeoutMillis
        }
    }
);

module.exports = seq
```

Eu fiz a seguinte mudança pra testar com sql server:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');    

const config = {
    user: "sa",
    database: "dbPortal",
    password: "",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1433,
    dialect: 'mssql',
    max: 10000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3000
};

const seq = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    {
        host:config.host,
        dialect:config.dialect,
        port:config.port,
        logging: false,
        pool: {
            max: config.max,
            min: 0,
            idle: config.idleTimeoutMillis
        }
    }
);

module.exports = seq
```

Quando ligo a API diz que foi conectada, mas logo em seguida diz que não foi. Quando vou testar ela, ela é POST, fica dando uns erros em vermelho no prompt.

Alguém sabe como configurar pra ela funcionar no SQL Server?

Comment: Voce deveria corrigir essa parte:
`host: "localhost"`, deveria ser algo como `host: "localhost\sqlexpress"` ou `host: "localhost\sql(sua versao)"`

Comment: A minha é o SQL server management studio, entao seria host: `"localhost\sqlmanagementstudio"` ?

Comment: quando vc abre o seu sql management qual path aparace em `Serve Name` esse deve ser o seu padrao do localhost

Comment: Não Maria, _SQL Server Management Studio_ é somente o programa usado para interagir com uma instânca do SQL Server, a instância do SQL Server pode estar rodando sem precisar do Management Studio, mas você precisa do Management Studio para visualizar suas bases, e suas tabelas, etc. Acho que o @HudsonPH estava se referindo ao nome da instância. Quando você entra no Management Studio, no Object Explorer, se você clicar com o botão direito no primeiro item e for em _Properties_ você poderá ver o nome da instância (General > Name).

Comment: Mas acho que o que você precisará é uma propriedade adicional para o Sequelize chamada `dialectOptions`, veja esse artigo: http://raathigesh.com/Connecting-To-MSSQL-with-Sequelize/

Comment: Eu coloquei, mas quando vou testar a API ele da o seguinte erro no prompt: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeHostNotFoundError: Failed to connect to MSSQLSERVERMARIA:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND MSSQLSERVERMARIA ...`

Comment: Colocou `MSSQLSERVERMARIA` direto na propriedade `host` ou na propriedade `dialectOptions`?

Comment: coloquei : `dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVERMARIA'
    }` em `host` eu acho que to colocando errado

Comment: E, como o @HudsonPH disse, quando você abre o Management Studio o valor que aparece em `Server name` é `localhost\MSSQLSERVERMARIA`?

Comment: nao, é: `GUI000123\MSSQLSERVERMARIA`

Comment: entao nao é localhost e sım `GUI000123\MSSQLSERVERMARIA`

Comment: faca o test com `host: "GUI000123\MSSQLSERVERMARIA"`

Comment: Isso, `localhost` significa que a instância está na própria máquina, `GUI000123` parece ser outra máquina na rede, então aparentemente o SQL Server está rodando em outra máquina e não nessa que você está usando (localhost).

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mas quando vou testar a API no postman nao carrega nada e no prompt da o erro `Unhandled rejection SequelizeHostNotFoundError: Failed to connect to GUI000123MSSQLSERVERMARIA:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND GUI000123MSSQLSERVERMARIA ....`

Comment: Então tenta fazer como estava no artigo: `host: 'GUI000123', dialectOptions: { instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVERMARIA' }`, aparentemente ele não aceita o _host+nome da instância_ no campo `host`.

Comment: Dessa forma tambem nao funciona

Comment: Aparentemente fica dando erro de `host`

Comment: Qual o erro exato?

Comment: da esse erro: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to GUI000624:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.connection.on.err (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\APIGuido-master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:99:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
 at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\APIGuido-master\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:875:14)
    at C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\APIGuido-master\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:740:25`

Comment: `at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\APIGuido-master\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:153:9)
    at Socket.onError (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\APIGuido-master\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:169:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com ajuda dos comentários na minha pergunta eu consegui resolver:

```
const config = {
    user: "sa",
    database: "Nomedb",
    password: "",
    host: "GUI122", //NOME QUE APARECE ANTES DA INSTANCIA DO MEU SQL
    port: 1433, //PORTA PADRAO SQL SERVER
    dialect: 'mssql',
    max: 10000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3000,
    instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVERMARIA' //INSTANCIA DO MEU SQL SERVER

};
```